# Stop AVAudioplayer from single button

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, avaudioplayer

I am trying to stop the alarm sound when the user tap the "Done" button. This is the code I am using now. I couldn't find any solution when it refers to use the same button.

```
@objc func runTimer() {

        if isTimerRunning {
            cafe.time -= 1

            if cafe.time <= 0 {
                timer.invalidate()
                let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "alarm_sound", withExtension: "mp3")
                alarmSound = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
                alarmSound.play()

                if alarmSound.isPlaying {
                    startButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)


                }
            }

@IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if !isTimerRunning {
            navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
            isTimerRunning = true
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            print("time")
            startButton.setTitle("Stop Brewing", for: .normal)
        } else {
            navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
            isTimerRunning = false
            resetTimer()
            startButton.setTitle("Start Brewing", for: .normal)
        }
        if startButton.currentTitle == "Done"{
          alarmSound.stop()
        }else{
          alarmSound.play()
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a variable to check audio is playing or not

```
var playing = false
```

set `playing = true` when your change your button text (done)

and apply below code in click event

```
@IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

if playing == true {
   alarmSound.stop()
}else{

alarmSound.play()

 }
}
```

Comment: it it work then upvote it so it will helpful for others

Comment: as soon as I get 15 reputation I will do it :)